# Windows tail program that lets you add blank lines

Tags: windows, tail

On Linux, when tailing a log, I can hit enter a couple times to give me a bit of separation in the output. Makes it easy to debug or just watch for things happening.

I've tried a couple of tail programs for Windows ("Tail for Win32" and "mTail") and they cannot do that. It's a bit painful to check the timestamps to find what the last set of lines that was dumped out. Rather than conduct an exhaustive survey myself, and because I didn't find this feature addressed here, I thought I'd ask the SO collective mind. Does this behaviour exist in any program for windows?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; should be on [su]

Comment: True. I can repost it over there on Monday. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Hoo WinTail](http://www.hootech.com/WinTail/) or [SnakeTail](http://snakenest.com/snaketail/), that supports the ability to make bookmarks. Maybe there are other [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/snaketail/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[Win Log Inspector](http://starredmediasoft.com/windows-log-inspector/)

It allows also to connect to a remote file by using http or ssh protocol